# I have a question about accessing 'member variable' in Future<Class>

Tags: flutter, dart, future

Hi:) I have a question about accessing 'member variable' in Future.

First, This is my implementation Code.

```
class FilterPacket {
  List<String> roomType;
  int minPrice;
  int maxPrice;
  String rentStart;
  String rentDone;

  int isParking;
  int isCCTV;
  int isWifi;
//Constructor exists, but omitted due to length
}
```

```
Future<FilterPacket> result = Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return new AllFilter();
                                      },
                                      fullscreenDialog: true
                                  ));

result.minPrice; // This is what I want to do
```

When I pop, I pass an argument of type 'FilterPacket' and after receiving it, I want to access the variable inside.

However, it seems that general access through '.' is not allowed due to Future characteristics.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'future characteristics'. There is a Future object that will eventually hold the result. You can do:

```
FilterPacket result = await Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return new AllFilter();
                                      },
                                      fullscreenDialog: true
                                  ));

result.minPrice;
```

Note that type of result variable is not Future, but Filter Packet, and you are waiting for future to complete with 'await'.

If you don't want to wait, other option would be something like:

```
Future<FilterPacket> result = Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return new AllFilter();
                                      },
                                      fullscreenDialog: true
                                  ));

result.then( (value) {value.minPrice /*do something with it here*/});
```